# Sharing a spark session

Tags: apache-spark

Lets say I have a python file *my_python.py* in which I have created a SparkSession 'spark' . I have a jar say *my_jar.jar* in which some spark logic is written. I am not creating SparkSession in my jar , rather I want to use the same session created in *my_python.py*. How to write a `spark-submit` command which take my python file , my jar and my sparksession 'spark' as an argument to my jar file.

Is it possible ?
If not , please share the alternative to do so.

Comment: have you tried doing SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() in the code that is in the jar?

Comment: He is talking about sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I feel there are two questions -

Q1. How in scala file you can reuse already created spark session?

Ans: Inside your scala code, you should use builder to get an existing session:

SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

Please check the Spark doc 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html

Q2: How you do spark-submit with a .py file as driver and scala jar(s) as supporting jars?

And: It should be in something like this

```
./spark-submit --jars myjar.jar,otherjar.jar --py-files path/to/myegg.egg path/to/my_python.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

So if you notice the method name, it is getOrCreate() - that means if a spark session is already created, no new session will be created rather existing session will be used.
Check this link for full implementation example:
https://www.crowdstrike.com/blog/spark-hot-potato-passing-dataframes-between-scala-spark-and-pyspark/

Comment: Thank you. It seems like what I want. I have one doubt though, how it knows which argument is for which file and how should i use them in my files ?

Comment: So all your arguments that you have given in spark-submit, will flow into the driver py file which in this example is my_python.py.

you have to have a main method in that py file and use sys.argv to receive the arguments.

inside that driver py file the code will look like
def main():
       source_path = sys.argv[1]


A small reminder, If the answer is useful please click the UP arrow beside the answer :-)

Comment: yeah i upvoted :) . I checked that link i am not able to understand how to use that session. Can you give me a small example, like, suppose I have created a sparksession 'myspark' using `myspark = SparkSession.builder.appname('sample').master("local").getOrCreate()` , how can i use this(myspark) session  (and dataframes created in this sessions) in my 2nd file (a javaspark jar). A simple and clear example would be helpful. Please update that in your answer :)

Comment: check the recent edit in answer, especially check the link